# Primefaces: Dialog with inputTextarea not updating controller's variable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have this Dialog:

```
 <p:dialog header="Ingrese Comentario" 
              widgetVar="dlg1" appendTo="@(body)" 
              modal="true" position="top"
              hideEffect="fold" showEffect="fold"
              closable="true" draggable="true"
              >
        <h:form id="d_ingresarComentario">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">           
            <p:inputTextarea   value="#{tareaController.comentarioNuevo.comentario}"
                               rows="7" cols="60"  
                               placeholder="Ingrese su comentario aquí" 
                               counter="display1" maxlength="200" 
                               counterTemplate="{0} Caracteres faltantes." 
                               >   
            </p:inputTextarea>  
            <br/>
            <h:outputText id="display1"/>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id ="c_enviar" 
                                 immediate="true"
                                 actionListener="#{tareaController.crearComentario()}"
                                 value="Enviar" 
                                 oncomplete="dlg1.hide()" global="false">                         
                </p:commandButton>    
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>   
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

The button's listener works fine, the text area is showed with the value's variable when the dialog is called.
But whenever I write in the text area the variable (comentarioNuevo.comentario), which is a string, is not updated in the controller. It always keep its initial value.
Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

I already tried: printing the variable's value on keyup, and yes it's always the same. 
Testing with other components, like h:inputTextArea or p:inputText and it have the same behavior, the variable wont get updated.
Yes, my variable have both getter and setter.

My controller's code looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TareaController implements Serializable {
private Comentario comentario = new Comentario();

    public void crearComentario() {
        comentarioDAO.crearComentario(login.getUsuario(), expediente, comentarioNuevo);
        nuevoComentario();
    }

    public Comentario getComentarioNuevo() {
        return comentarioNuevo;
    }

    public void setComentarioNuevo(Comentario comentarioNuevo) {
        this.comentarioNuevo = comentarioNuevo;
    }
}
```

That Comentario is a JPA Entity, which works fine in other sides of the 
Aditional Information: PrimeFaces version 4.0, Mojarra 2.7, JSF 2.2

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set `immediate=true` on a UICommandComponent, so the "Update model values" phase is skipped. Remove the attribute and it should work.

BalusC offers this advice, "If set in UICommand only, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the UIInput component(s). Use this to skip the entire processing of the form. E.g. 'Cancel' or 'Back' button."

#### See also

- [Add immediate="true" to UICommand only](http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#AddImmediateTrueToUICommandOnly)
- [Okay, when should I use the immediate attribute?](http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute) (same article)

Comment: Dammit Jimmy, that was easy. Thank you for the tip. I should've read that balus blog before, seems useful.